# Undefined Method Model Path, Form_for not saving, Posted Correctly, Rails Framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails

sorry I am new to rails

Right now I am trying to build a small application just like https://pinboard.in, I am trying to get a summer internship with them.

Here is my Bookmark model

```
class Bookmark < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :url, :title, :description, :counter 
  belongs_to :user 

  #validates that url has https:// or http://
  validates :url, :format => { :with => /(^$)|(^(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-  9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(([0-9]{1,5})?\/.*)?$)/ix,
  :message => "Invalid URL" }
end
```

Here is my bookmark controller

```
class BookmarksController < ApplicationController
    def add_bookmark
        @bookmark = Bookmark.new 

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html 
        end 
    end 

    def draw_recent
        @bookmarks = Bookmark.all
    end 
end
```

Here is my form

```
<%= form_for :bookmark do |f| %>
    URL: <%= f.text_field :url %><br/>
    Title: <%= f.text_field :title %><br/>
    Description: <%= f.text_field :description %><br/>
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Everything get rendered correctly and when I put in the information and submit add

here is my output

```
Started POST "/add" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-09 09:55:58 -0400
Processing by BookmarksController#add_bookmark as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",    "authenticity_token"=>"ZCxA226pOVyu5AkQAmvvfKz5uPQ4gFggPTwrswtqZYk=", "bookmark"=>  {"url"=>"http://litmus.com", "title"=>"Email marketing ", "description"=>"email marketing "},  "commit"=>"Submit"}
Rendered bookmarks/_form.html.erb (1.9ms)
Rendered bookmarks/add_bookmark.html.erb within layouts/application (3.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 96ms (Views: 95.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I have two thoughts in my head, well my form is posting it correctly but somehow it is not saving anything to my db, do I need a save method in my controller?

when I try @bookmark instead of :bookmark the app throws me an error saying wrong bookmarks.path

```
undefined method `bookmarks_path
```

I understand the former you are actually working with the instance @bookmark in the controller and the latter is wrapping around the model....

Can someone enlighten me? i feel like this is very trivial for you guys... :)

Comment: Do you also have `resources :bookmarks` in your config/routes.rb and what error you are actually greeted with on webpage?

Answer (score 1):

Should be form_for @bookmark do |f|. You are getting the `undefined method` error because you have not defined your routes in config/routes.rb, add there:

```
resources :bookmarks
```

That will add the RESTful resources following the CRUD convention, so you should change the name of your controller methods for this to work out-of-the-box. You will need at least three methods for what you are doing right now:

In your app/controllers/bookmarks_controller.rb:

First one will render your form at /bookmarks/new

```
def new
  @bookmark = Bookmark.new
end
```

Second one will process the form submission (no action is needed from you apart that following the naming convention)

```
def create
  @bookmark = Bookmark.new(params[:bookmark])
  @bookmark.save
end
```

Third one to show the bookmarks as in your current 'draw_recent'

```
def index
  @bookmark = Bookmark.all
end
```

Afterwards you can go on validating the data, etc but the basic flow should be like that.

It is better to start with the conventions to go later on to change the method standard names when you have more confidence.